# how to create array in c# for android

Tags: c#, android, arrays, xamarin.android

Not found what i'm looking for yet so here's my last resort.

How do i create an array in c# for android that i can write a string of characters too?

I have an editText box and a button.. i want to enter text into the editText box and then store the data input to the array when the button is clicked.

I would really appreciate code examples as i really don't understand this and there isn't anything that i've found out there about doing this in c# for android. Thanks.

Comment: Why not just use a `string`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an array using:

```
string[] strArr = editText.Text.Split('\n');
```

Or something very similar.  Basically you are treating the input as a delimited string, a la a CSV, however in this case the delimiter is the newline character.  If you need to access strArr on a larger basis you just declare it outside the method at the top of the class.

Comment: Thank you :) do you know how i would go about implementing the button into this? So that after the text is in the field, clicking the button stores it to the array..

Comment: I haven't ventured into C# (Monodroid) yet.  Give me about 6 weeks and I'll be neck deep in Monodroid and Monotouch.  That's a different question all together.